# python extract songs from radio streaming

Tags: python

My task is to extract full songs from radio streaming using python 2.7.
I have managed to record radio streaming, but I can't find a good way to detect if the audio that I record is music, ads, or just talking. 
I tried to detect by threshold, but it wasn't good because there are not enough silence between the talking or the ads to the songs.
If someone knows a good solution for me I would love to hear about it.

`import pydub
streamAudio = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("justRadioStream.mp3")
listMp3 = pydub.silence.detect_silence(streamAudio, min_silence_len=400, silence_thresh=-38)
print listMp3`

I tried to play with the min_silence_len and silence_thresh, but there is not enough time of silence between songs and ads or talking, or louder voice to detect properly

thanks a lot!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: You could use the silences between ads and music, record everything and decide by length of the recorded slices what to keep.

Comment: Thanks!, but that's what I tried to do, but most of the time there is not enough silence between them. I'm looking for another way

Comment: What is "not enough silence" ? Can you show some code at least so we can help with that too?

Comment: Answered at the post

Comment: There is a `split_on_silence` function, did you try it with that? Use some little silence length like 100ms.

Comment: Yes I've tried, basically does the same as detect_silence, instead of displaying the silence time it's displaying the time with voice

Answer (score 0):

This is not the kind of problem that will be solved in a couple of lines of Python.  The problem is under-specified - there's no guarantee that there will even be silence between songs, ads and announcers on any given radio stream, as they try to make it harder to usefully record full songs from their streams for piracy purposes.

To do this robustly, it's likely that you'll need to apply AI / deep learning techniques to distinguish music from ads and announcements.  Even then it's tricky, as some music will have regular talking in it, some songs are short, and some ads are long and contain music.